# Pika connection to RabbitMQ remote server using ssh tunel

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

The queues run on port `5672` if I run the code on the cluster, but from my PC I am using port forwarding:

```
ssh -L15674:white-ball.company.com:15672 myusername@server.company.com
```

Then, I open http://localhost:15674 where I have my username and password.

What should be the **rabbitServer** and **rabbitPort**? I have tried different option but I am having connection error or pika.exceptions.IncompatibleProtocolError: StreamLostError: ('Transport indicated EOF',)

```py
import pika
def producer():
    try:
        rabbitUserName = 'myusername'
        rabbitPassword = 'mypassword'
        rabbitServer = '127.0.0.1'
        rabbitPort = 5674
        rabbitQueue = 'test'
        virtual_host= "something"

        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(rabbitUserName, rabbitPassword)
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(rabbitServer, rabbitPort,virtual_host, credentials))

        channel = connection.channel()

        channel.queue_declare(queue= rabbitQueue)
        message="test"
        
        channel.basic_publish (exchange='', routing= 'test', body= message)

        print(f"Data sent {message}")
    except Exception as e:
        raise
    
producer()
```

Comment: 15672 is the http listener, but your app wants to connect via amqp on 5672 -> add another tunnel for the amqp port: ssh -L5674:white-ball.company.com:5672 myusername@server.company.com